# How can I run a https server on Heroku with docker?

Tags: .net, docker, heroku, webapi

I have a .net core 3.1 web api that I wrap in a docker image for release on heroku. As standard, I have enabled HTTPS and redirection from HTTP to HTTPS for my server. It works well as a standalone component, as well as within docker.

The problem arises when Heroku comes into picture. I can reach my application, but it looks like the HTTP port is the one that heroku routers pick and I get naturally a redirection (status 307):
`2021-01-28T23:39:23.806237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/matches" host=stg-inform-web-api.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=307 bytes=192 protocol=https`

How am I supposed to deal with this? Is it the case that I don't really need https internally for this infrastructure setting for my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku takes care of deploying your application, providing a hostname (myapp.herokuapp.com) and SSL (access via HTTPS).
You need to make sure your web application can bind to the port assigned at runtime by Heroku, this is provided in the $PORT env variable.

The web layer is provided by Heroku so your app only need to accept HTTP requests.

Comment: So should I understand that it's not antipattern to disable the https redirection for my server in this situation? Is this the same in a production environment?

Comment: It is not anti pattern in way that HTTPS will be ensured by Heroku: your app runs behing the Heroku web servers and it is not exposed to the internet (hence running on http is fine if not preferable - ie lighter)